# jquery selector li:selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using simple jquery selector but unfortunately didn't get the required result.
my code is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var displayName = $('.divclass').find('ul').find('li:first').text();
  if ($('.divclass').find('ul').find('li:selected').length) {
    displayName = $('.divclass').find('ul').find('li:selected').text();
  }
  $('divclass').find('button').html(displayName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divclass">
  <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="true">
    sometext
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">sometext1</a>
    </li>
    <li selected="selected">
      <a href="#">sometext2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">sometext3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I called it on document.ready. It executes but did not give me the proper result, what I am doing wrong to select the `li` with selected attribute.

Comment: `selected` isn't a valid attribute for an `li`, so `:selected` won't work. You could put a class on the element and select that instead.

Comment: @rory I just want its text even then it will not work?

Comment: No, as `:selected` cannot work for `li` elements

Comment: `<li data-selected=selected>` could work, I suppose: `...find('li[data-selected=selected]')` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:selected` has [a specific meaning](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/): An `option` element that is currently selected. Perhaps somewhat counter-intuitively, that selected state is not reflected in an attribute (just the default) and again, it only applies to `option` elements.

`selected` isn't a valid attribute for `li` elements. You could either use `data-selected` for your own flag attribute, or a class.

If you used `data-selected`, you'd use `[data-selected]` in the selector:

```html
<li selected="selected">
```

```js
...find('ul').find('li[data-selected]').length...
```

...and then add/remove the attribute as appropriate.

If you use a class instead, it's a class selector:

```html
<li class="selected">
```

```js
...find('ul').find('li.selected').length...
```

...and then you add/remove the class as appropriate.